# SQL Server: Delete Rows with NULL FK faster?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a huge table tblTraffic, which has many columns:

```
Id, date, year, month, day, ReferenceId, data1, data2, data3....
```

The table has more than 1 billion rows, the size is about 1TB. It also has many indexes and FK.

Over time, we want to purge some old data. But, it turns out that the delete is slow in this case. After some investigation, we figured out that it is because of one FK (`ReferecenId`). So, we drop the FK. Now, the batch delete of this table is much faster.

The FK is from table `tblReference`, which has about 200 million rows:

```
ReferenceId, TrafficId, data1, data2, ...
```

Now, because we dropped FK to batch delete data in `tblTraffic`, some rows in `tblReference` have NULL FK in `tblTraffic`. We want to delete all these from `tblReference`. There are not many rows like this in `tblReference`.

```
DELETE *
FROM tblReference 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tblTraffic
                  WHERE tblTraffic.Id = tblReference.TrafficId)
```

We try batch delete for this, but it is slow. Are there any suggestions for this?

We are using SQL Server and C#.

Thanks

Comment: Without some details this is impossible to answer. Things like table definitions, including indexes. Maybe sharing the actual execution plan from a delete.

Comment: How many rows would be deleted?

Comment: You don't seem to care so much about maintaining referential integrity, so why not select the min referenceid from tblTraffic, and then delete all tblReference where id < than that? (hopefully these are ints, not guids)

Comment: Is the field `tblReference.TrafficId` indexed or not? Of course, it would need to be the first field in a relevant index - and a FK is not inherently an index. If it is not indexed, you are performing a table scan.  If it isn't indexed, you should be able to speed up the delete by creating a #temp table with the PK and the TrafficId from tblReference, indexing the TrafficId with an INCLUDE of the PK, and using that for your joining check.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: your `tblTraffic` has `Id (assume PK)` and `ReferenceId` and `tblReference`  has `ReferenceId (assume PK)` and `TrafficId` - why? It seems doubly linked?

Answer (score 0):

you can put index on the aforamentioned column and then delete accordingly (if you have enough resources available).

Also delete works faster if you disable unneeded indexes for the delete operation.

And If you divide your delete operation into chunks it will be even more resource friendly.

you can also consider to use `degree of parallelism`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative option, you may try and use a `LEFT JOIN`ed combined with a `WHERE ... IS NULL`.

```
DELETE ref
FROM 
    tblReference ref
    LEFT JOIN tblTraffic tra
        ON tra.Id = ref.TrafficId
WHERE tra.TrafficId IS NULL
```

Depending on your actual database set up, this might perform faster than a nested subquery.

I would also recommend setting up an index on column `Id` in table `tblTraffic` before running this query.

Another optimization would be to temporarily disable all constraints and indexes on table `tblReference` during the `DELETE` (including a potential index on `tblReference.TrafficId`) : this will prevent the RDBMS from recomputing the indexes during the deletion, which can be costly if there are many rows to delete.